# How to import a class from a py file to a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-import

In the same directory, I have a file named pyfile.py with this code:

```
class Data_dict:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {'Mary': 'Silver'}
```

and a Jupyter notebook with the code:

```
import pyfile
d = Data_dict()
```

The import succeeds but I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'Data_dict' is not defined
```

How can I import the class Data_dict?

Comment: `d = pyfile.Data_dict()`?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried loading the python file in the notebook cell?

```
%load pyfile.py
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `import pyfile` only the module is imported and not other names inside the module if you need the `Data_dict` class then you need to import it as well. Also, you can use names inside the module with `module_name.anything`.

In your case, you can do something like this.

**Import everything from inside pyfile**

```
from pyfile import *
d = Data_dict()
```

**Only import the Data_dict class**

```
from pyfile import Data_dict
d = Data_dict()
```

**Import the module and then access members through it**

```
import pyfile
d = pyfile.Data_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `pyfile.Data_dict()` or `from pyfile import Data_dict`?

Comment: With the brackets () it's invalid syntax. Without them I get an import error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Data_dict'

Comment: Yes, the parenthesis were a mistake. You may also try ```from pyfile import *```. Does this help now?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of the pyfile and somehow it got fixed. Not sure what was the problem, I think it could be related to the fact that I previously had a notebook with the same name.
Thanks.